# Assign workspaces on i3 to multiple displays

Tags: i3, workspaces

I've switched on using i3 on my Linux laptop. I'm usually using only the laptop's internal monitor (display `eDP1`), but when I'm at work I tend to connect a secondary monitor to my computer's HDMI port (display `HDMI2`). So far, I've made this work fine by adding these commands to my i3 config file:

```
# use workspaces on different monitors
workspace "1: P1" output eDP1
workspace "2: P2" output eDP1
workspace "3: P3" output eDP1
workspace "4: P4" output eDP1
workspace "5: P5" output eDP1
workspace "6: S1" output HDMI2 
workspace "7: S2" output HDMI2
workspace "8: S3" output HDMI2
workspace "9: S4" output HDMI2
workspace "10: S5" output HDMI2

# add HDMI monitor when connected
exec --no-startup-id xrandr --output HDMI2 --right-of eDP1
bindsym $mod+m exec --no-startup-id xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --right-of eDP1
```

In other words, when I connect my HDMI display I just press <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to get i3 to detect it, place it right of my primary display, and delegate 5 named workspaces (6-10) to it.

**Here's the problem:** At home, I have another monitor that I can connect with VGA (display `DP2`). I can run the `xrandr` command above to place this display to the right of my primary display as well, but I can't get the workspaces to be assigned to this display by default, unless I *replace* the rules I already have for my HDMI monitor. I would like both these workspaces to work the same no matter which monitor I use, so this is not an option.

**TL;DR** Is there a way to assign workspaces to two different displays, depending on which display is connected (assuming they never will be connected at the same time)?

Answer (score 32):

You can't assign multiple outputs to single workspace, see: https://github.com/i3/i3/issues/555

So the only way is to change i3 config dynamically. You could assign to hotkey script that will be doing 2 things: changing monitor outputs with `xrandr` and moving workspaces with `i3-msg`:

```
xrandr --output DP2 --auto --right-of eDP1
i3-msg "workspace 6, move workspace to output DP2"
...
i3-msg "workspace 10, move workspace to output DP2"
```

With above script you will move 6-10 workspaces to DP2 and end up staying on workspace 10.

**Update 2019:**
Multiple outputs assignment was implemented starting from v4.16, see https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#workspace_screen. Now you could use them like that:

```
workspace "6: S1" output HDMI2 VGA
```

The first available output will then be used.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [user's guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#workspace_screen), syntax:

```
workspace 1 output eDP1
...
workspace 6 output HDMI2 VGA
```

should work.

Or you may define primary output on your machines, if not set (`xrandr --output <output> --primary`), and use this syntax:

```
workspace 1 output primary
...
workspace 6 output secondary
```